# Change 1d array to 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays

How would i go about converting the following 1d arrays into 2d arrays? I am kind of confused when working with 2d arrays.

```
[100, 101, 102, 200, 201, 202, 300, 301, 302] [232, 123, 102, 200, 321, 202,  300, 301, 302]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `2D Array` is nothing just an array of arrays, so you can put these two array into a 2D array, every element of a 2D array is an array.

```
int[] arr1 = {100, 101, 102, 200, 201, 202, 300, 301, 302};
int[] arr2 = {232, 123, 102, 200, 321, 202,  300, 301, 302};
int[][] array2D = new int[2][];
array2D[0] = arr1;
array2D[1] = arr2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to create a 2D array with the dimensions wished, then use an outer and inner for loop to transfer values. For example:

```
int k = 0
//array declarations
for (int i = 0...)
  for (int j = 0...)
    if (k < array1D.length)
      array2D[i][j] = array1D[k];
      k++
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     int[] x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
     int [][]z = new int[4][4];
     for (int i = 0, k=0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int jl = 0; jl < 4; jl++)
             z[i][jl] = x[k++];
     for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
     {
         System.out.println();
            for(int jl=0;jl<4;jl++)
              {
                 System.out.print(z[i][jl]+" ");
              }
     }
```

Hope you have got answer to your problem.Happy coding